# Autoincrement column over partition by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `#tBookPrice` has data with `calcId`. I need to add data to the `#tBookPrice` that increases the artificial `calcId` in the context of the `code`.

I have code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tBookPrice;

CREATE TABLE #tBookPrice
(
    id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(256),
    code VARCHAR(256),
    price INTEGER,
    calcId INTEGER
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tBookPriceTmp;

CREATE TABLE #tBookPriceTmp
(
     id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
     name VARCHAR(256),
     price INTEGER,
     code VARCHAR(256)
);

INSERT INTO #tBookPrice (name, code, price, calcId)
VALUES
     ('Name 1', 'B56878', 10, 1),
     ('Name 2', 'H56817', 10, 1),
     ('Name 3', 'Y55617', 10, 1);

INSERT INTO #tBookPriceTmp (name, code, price)
VALUES
     ('Name 1', 'B56878', 20),
     ('Name 1', 'B56878', 30),
     ('Name 1', 'B56878', 40);

INSERT INTO #tBookPrice (name, code, price, calcId)
    SELECT
        tmp.name, 
        tmp.code,
        tmp.price,
        (maxCode.maxId + 1) AS calcId
    FROM 
        #tBookPriceTmp AS tmp
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT
             code, 
             MAX(calcId) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code ASC) AS maxId
         FROM 
             #tBookPrice) AS maxCode ON tData.code = maxCode.code

SELECT *
FROM #tBookPrice
ORDER BY code, calcId ASC
```

I have an error in calcId:

```
id  name    code    price   calcId
----------------------------------
1   Name 1  B56878  10      1
4   Name 1  B56878  20      2
5   Name 1  B56878  30      2
6   Name 1  B56878  40      2
2   Name 2  H56817  10      1
3   Name 3  Y55617  10      1
```

I need `calcId` to be like this:

```
id  name    code    price   calcId
----------------------------------
1   Name 1  B56878    10      1
4   Name 1  B56878    20      2
5   Name 1  B56878    30      3
6   Name 1  B56878    40      4
2   Name 2  H56817    10      1
3   Name 3  Y55617    10      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding 1 to the max value is always a constant. You need to add the row_number to the max value e.g.

```
INSERT INTO #tBookPrice (name, code, price, calcId)
    SELECT
        td.name 
        , td.code
        , td.price
        , mc.maxId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY td.price ASC) AS calcId
    FROM #tBookPriceTmp AS td
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            code
            , MAX(calcId) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code ASC) AS maxId
        FROM #tBookPrice
    ) AS mc ON mc.code = td.code;
```

Note: Table aliases are meant to be short to make the query more concise and readable.

Comment: Hot take - aliases, variables, etc should aid in understanding/readability. I'll take "maxCode" over "mc" any day. Your opinion is also fine but it's just that - an opinion.